# rack-rewrite redirect ALL subdomains to root domain (except root)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-rewrite

How do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in rack-rewrite syntax?

Comment: This gem safe me :) https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new middleware for this

```
class SubdomainToWwwMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if !request.host.starts_with?("www.")
      [301, { "Location" => request.url.gsub(/\/\/([^\.]*)/, "//www") }, self]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

This is untested but should put you in the right direction. You will likely want to add a condition to check not just for `www.example.com` but also `example.com`. The middleware above might blow up currently in that case.

You can put this in `/lib/middleware/subdomain_to_www_middleware.rb`, add

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{ config.root }/lib/middleware )
```

to your `config/application.config`, and

```
config.middleware.use "SubdomainToWwwMiddleware"
```

to your `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: I followed your steps and got the error: TypeError (can't convert Regexp into String):
  lib/middleware/subdomain_to_www_middleware.rb:9:in `gsub'
  lib/middleware/subdomain_to_www_middleware.rb:9:in `call'